# How do I load a text file line by line into an array with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I load a text file line by line into an `array` with `swift`?

Comment: See this post for an excellent discussion on the options for converting a text file to a line array. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/100813/79551

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
func arrayFromContentsOfFileWithName(fileName: String) -> [String]? {
    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: "txt") else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    } catch _ as NSError {
        return nil
    }
}
```

This approach assumes the file in question is located in your app bundle.

Comment: What if the file is located outside the main bundle? Assume that I have an `NSString` that contains the full path.

Comment: this is a first time I saw the `guard` statement

Answer (score 10):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you can choose one of the 3 following ways in order to solve your problem.

---

### #1. Using `StringProtocol`'s `components(separatedBy:)` method

`Foundation` provides `String` a method called [`components(separatedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923375-components) with the following declaration:

```
func components(separatedBy separator: CharacterSet) -> [String]
```

> Returns an array containing substrings from the string that have been divided by characters in the given set.

The code sample below shows how to use `components(separatedBy:)` with its parameter set to [`CharacterSet.newlines`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1780325-newlines) in order to load the content of a text file line by line into an array:

```
import Foundation

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Lorem Ipsum", ofType: "txt")!
let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let lines = text.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)

print(lines)
```

As an alternative, you can use the [overloading of `components(separatedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126752-components) that takes a parameter of type `String`. The code sample below shows how to use it:

```
import Foundation

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Lorem Ipsum", ofType: "txt")!
let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let lines = text.components(separatedBy: "\n")

print(lines)
```

⚠️ You should however prefer the overloading of `components(separatedBy:)` that takes a `CharacterSet` parameter and use it with the value `CharacterSet.newlines` as this will manage all new line characters (U+000A ~ U+000D, U+0085, U+2028, and U+2029).

---

### #2. Using `StringProtocol`'s `enumerateSubstrings(in:options:_:)` method

`Foundation` provides `String` a method called [`enumerateSubstrings(in:options:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/3126756-enumeratesubstrings). The code sample below shows how to use `enumerateSubstrings(in:options:_:)` with `options` parameter value set to `String.EnumerationOptions.byLines` in order to load the content of a text file line by line into an array:

```
import Foundation

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Lorem Ipsum", ofType: "txt")!
let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

let range = text.startIndex ..< text.endIndex
var lines = [String]()
text.enumerateSubstrings(in: range, options: String.EnumerationOptions.byLines) {
    (substring, range, enclosingRange, stop) in
    guard let substring = substring else { return }
    lines.append(substring)
}

print(lines)
```

---

### #3. Using `NLTokenizer`'s `enumerateTokens(in:using:)` method

`NLTokenizer` has a method called [`enumerateTokens(in:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nltokenizer/3017463-enumeratetokens). `enumerateTokens(in:using:)` has the following declaration:

```
@nonobjc func enumerateTokens(in range: Range<String.Index>, using block: (Range<String.Index>, NLTokenizer.Attributes) -> Bool)
```

> Enumerates over a given range of the string and calls the specified block for each token.

The code sample below shows how to use `enumerateTokens(in:using:)` in order to load the content of a text file line by line into an array:

```
import Foundation
import NaturalLanguage

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Lorem Ipsum", ofType: "txt")!
let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

let tokenizer = NLTokenizer(unit: .paragraph)
tokenizer.setLanguage(.english)
tokenizer.string = text

var lines = [String]()
tokenizer.enumerateTokens(in: text.startIndex ..< text.endIndex) { (range, attributes) -> Bool in
    let line = String(text[range])
    lines.append(line)
    return true
}
print(lines)
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 version based on the accepted answer:

```
func arrayFromContentsOfFileWithName(fileName: String) -> [String]? {
    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") else {
        return nil
    }

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to be nit-picky, but the signature might be better as `func arrayFromContentsOfFile(with fileName: String) -> [String]?`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are in Swift 2.0, you should use:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: nil)
if path == nil {
  return nil
}

var fileContents: String? = nil
do {
  fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} catch _ as NSError {
  return nil
}
```

Comment: You forgot `var lineArray = fileContents.componantsSeparedByString("\n")`

Answer (score 5):

This works only until Xcode 6.1 beta 1. In 6.1 beta 2 you must write this:

```
var err: NSError? = NSError()
let s = String(contentsOfFile: fullPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)
```

Where `fullPath` is a string containing the full path to the file and `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is a predefined constant for UTF8-Encoding.

You can also use `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` for Mac files or `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` for Windows files.

`s` is an optional String and you can look if reading the file was successful:

```
if (s != nil)
{
    return (s!) // Return the string as "normal" string, not as optional string
}
```

Comment: This also seems to have ceased to work as of the final release of Xcode 6. Try let string = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(fullPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error:&error)

Answer (score 2):

My simple coding for you

```
 let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("FileName", ofType: "txt")
 var text = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!
 println(text)
 var array = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: <#FileName#>, ofType: "txt")
{
    do
    {
        let str = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return str.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
else
{
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me works as follow:

```
let myFileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("listacomuni", withExtension: "txt")!
let myText = try! String(contentsOfURL: myFileURL, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
print(String(myText))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a csv file of numeric data. (based on Cezar's answer)

```
func get_csv_data() -> [[Double]] {
    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("filename_without_extension", ofType: "csv") else {
        return []
    }
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let line_str_array = content.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        return line_str_array.map {
            let field_str_array = $0.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
            return field_str_array.map {
                Double($0)!
            }
        }
    } catch _ as NSError {
        return []
    }
}
```